# GeoDjango's within and contains queryset filters differ to direct GEOS lookups

Tags: django, gis, spatial, geodjango, django-queryset

I've got two models, one which has areas and one which has points. I'm trying to do some simple lookups when the point-model is saved (sends a message to users in who's area the point appears).

The following code is from within a post_save signal handler.

```
(Pdb)   PointBasedModel.objects.filter(location=instance.location)
[<PointBasedModel: on 2011-12-03 16:05:52>, <PointBasedModel: on 2011-12-03 16:05:52>]

(Pdb)   PointBasedModel.objects.filter(location__within=PolyBasedModel.objects.all()[0].area)
[<PointBasedModel: on 2012-01-03 17:36:51>, <PointBasedModel: on 2011-12-03 16:05:52>, <PointBasedModel: on 2011-12-03 16:05:52>, <PointBasedModel: on 2011-11-09 19:53:34>, <PointBasedModel: on 2011-11-09 19:53:34>, <PointBasedModel: on 2011-11-06 15:24:31>, <PointBasedModel: on 2011-10-17 07:40:39>, <PointBasedModel: on 2011-02-27 20:46:04>]

(Pdb) PolyBasedModel.objects.filter(area__contains=PointBasedModel.objects.filter(location__within=PolyBasedModel.objects.all()[0].area)[0].location)
[]
```

As you can see, it is possible to retrieve the instance that I have just created, then find all the PolyBasedModels in which that PointBasedModel instance appears, filtering the PolyBasedModel back using the PointBasedModel that is known to be within the Poly, fails.

The code is a little contrived to demonstrate the problem, but simply put, this is what I'm seeing:

```
(pdb) PolyBasedModel.objects.filter(area__contains=instance.location)
[]
(pdb) instance.location.within(PolyBasedModel.objects.get(pk=2).area)
True
(Pdb) PolyBasedModel.objects.get(pk=2).area.contains(instance.location)
True
```

It makes no sense... Anyone had a similar problem/know a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little more digging, I found this problem:

```
(Pdb) str(PolyBasedModel.objects.filter(area__contains='POINT (-2.6203333333300001 51.4453333332999989)').query)
*** AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'ewkb'
```

A quick search for `'str' object has no attribute 'ewkb'` revealed http://groups.google.com/group/geodjango/browse_thread/thread/11a3016a0aeceec9 which points out that you have to be using a GeoManager... obviously.

Changing the PolyBasedModel to use a GeoManager fixed it.

I guess that's what you get for converting from non-geospatial to geospatial! Do it right first time. :-)